# How to check if Javascript Promise has been fulfilled?

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise, jquery-deferred

I have modified this [example](https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/317/how-to-check-if-a-javascript-promise-has-been-fulfilled-rejected-or-resolved) a little by adding loop and Deferred object to know all promise have been fulfilled.

What I want to do is to push all promise into an array and print them out when all are fulfilled.

Here is my code:

```
get_data();

function get_data() {


  var myPromise = [];
  var calls = [];
  var resultset = '';
  for (var j = 0, k = 5; j < k; j++) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    var p = get_result();
    if (p.isPending()) {
      console.log('pending');
    }
    p.then(function(resultset) {
      if (p.isFulfilled()) {
        myPromise.push(resultset);
        calls.push(d);
      }
    });

  }

  $.when.apply($, calls).then(function() {
    console.log(myPromise); // always prints an empty array.
  });
}

function get_result() {

  return MakeQuerablePromise(new Promise(function(result, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      result("Yeah !");
    }, 10000);
  }));
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sonubreeze/0qdnb3gp/) for complete code**

Comment: `Promise.all` seems to be what you actually want, rather than using jquery *almost* promises kludge called Deferred

Comment: @JaromandaX can you post an example ? Thanks

Comment: Not really because I can't understand your code *at all* - I just picked up what you said about waiting for **all Promises** to resolve - which sounds like a perfect fit for `Promise.all` - whose documentation is available to everyone https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you populate the `calls` array **after** each deferred has fulfilled. This means that `calls` is still empty when you run `$.when.apply($, calls)`, and thus since there are no unfulfilled deferreds it will resolve immediately, before any of the calls has actually fulfilled.

Your code is also needlessly convoluted. As has been suggested, you have much to gain from using the Promise interface and `Promise.all()`. In your case, I would do something like this:

```
function get_data() {


  var calls = [];
  for (var j = 0, k = 5; j < k; j++) {
    calls.push(get_result());
  }

  Promise.all(calls).then(function(results) {
    console.log(results); // results is an array containing the result from each call.
  });
}
```

There's no need to check if a promise has resolved, the `then` callback will be invoked once it resolves. If a promise instead gets rejected, this should be handled by using a `catch` callback somewhere in the promise chain. And those are the only two possible outcomes of a promise.

---

P.S. A separate issue with your code is that you always push the last deferred created in the loop to the `calls` array. This is because `d` is scoped outside of the for loop and, then reassigned in each iteration and by the time the asynchronous calls resolve it has already been assigned the final deferred.

Comment: Thanks Mikael. Just one question: would this work for ajax ?

Comment: Note that the Promise object is not IE friendly

Comment: @Snappy That's up to the AJAX implementation, but generally yes, pretty much all modern AJAX libraries/frameworks support promises

Comment: @PhilLucks Yeah, but then again, what is? ;) ... I would recommend using a polyfill for that rather than using jQuery's weird deferreds.

Answer (score 4):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

> The **Promise.all**(iterable) method returns a single Promise that resolves when all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
var p1 = Promise.resolve(3);
var p2 = 1337;
var p3 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   setTimeout(resolve, 100, 'foo');
}); 

Promise.all([p1, p2, p3]).then(values => { 
  console.log(values); // [3, 1337, "foo"] 
});
```